# When using Snappy, Raspberry Pi 3 WiFi hangs

Tags: networking, kernel, application-development, ubuntu-core

I've been attempting to use the Snappy Core 16 image with a Raspberry Pi 3.  The system boots, is able to scan WiFi but hangs at 66% when I attempt to associate (this is true even when it remembers the settings, and associates after saving the configuration).  I've seen some people mention that the problem is related to power management of the WiFi module, but sense it's Snappy, it doesn't seem to be a simple matter to change the network configuration to disable this.

Is it my particular WiFi power management?  (AirPort 802.11ac)

Here is the relevant lines form the kernel:

```
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   16.000108] brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   16.009258] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   16.009275] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   16.009284] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   16.009299] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   16.009311] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   16.009324] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   16.009339] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   16.009354] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   16.009367] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   16.009379] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   16.009391] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   19.243991] audit: type=1400 audit(1493440107.711:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=1062 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   19.245434] audit: type=1400 audit(1493440107.715:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=1062 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   19.497100] audit: type=1400 audit(1493440107.963:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=1061 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   19.500015] audit: type=1400 audit(1493440107.967:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1061 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   19.502673] audit: type=1400 audit(1493440107.971:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=1061 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   19.505159] audit: type=1400 audit(1493440107.971:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=1061 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   19.594047] audit: type=1400 audit(1493440108.063:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.core.hook.configure" pid=1080 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   20.668611] brcmf_add_if: ERROR: netdev:wlan0 already exists
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   20.684127] brcmf_add_if: ignore IF event
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   20.704243] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   20.704281] brcmfmac: power management disabled
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   20.711930] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   21.005663] brcmf_add_if: ERROR: netdev:wlan0 already exists
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   21.020429] brcmf_add_if: ignore IF event
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   21.139726] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
Apr 29 04:28:29 localhost kernel: [   21.140181] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Apr 29 04:28:30 localhost kernel: [   21.778844] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Apr 29 04:28:30 localhost kernel: [   21.830572] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
Apr 29 04:28:30 localhost kernel: [   21.830597] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: FCC
Apr 29 04:28:30 localhost kernel: [   21.830607] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Apr 29 04:28:30 localhost kernel: [   21.830622] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 3000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 29 04:28:30 localhost kernel: [   21.830638] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 1700 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 29 04:28:30 localhost kernel: [   21.830653] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (0 s)
Apr 29 04:28:30 localhost kernel: [   21.830666] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (0 s)
Apr 29 04:28:30 localhost kernel: [   21.830678] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 3000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 29 04:28:30 localhost kernel: [   21.830690] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 29 04:28:31 localhost kernel: [   23.267222] audit: type=1400 audit(1493440111.735:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.core.hook.configure" pid=1259 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 29 04:28:32 localhost kernel: [   24.190638] audit: type=1400 audit(1493440112.659:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.core.hook.configure" pid=1307 comm="apparmor_parser"
```